# Can I use Composite Primary Keys this way in Gorm? Why SQLSTATE 42830 error?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to create these tables with composite primary keys:

```golang
type Tenant struct {
    gorm.Model

    Description string
}

type BaseModel struct {
    gorm.Model

    TenantID uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Tenant   Tenant
}

type Player struct {
    BaseModel

    Name string
    Teams []Team
}

type Team struct {
    BaseModel

    Name     string
    PlayerID uint
}
```

but If I use:

```golang
myDB.AutoMigrate(
  &Tenant{},
  &Player{},
  &Team{},
)
```

it throws with:

```
C:/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/driver/postgres@v1.1.0/migrator.go:157 ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "players" (SQLSTATE 42830)
[15.960ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE "teams" ("id" bigserial,"created_at" timestamptz,"updated_at" timestamptz,"deleted_at" timestamptz,"tenant_id" bigint,"name" text,"player_id" bigint,PRIMARY KEY ("id","tenant_id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_teams_tenant" FOREIGN KEY ("tenant_id") REFERENCES "tenants"("id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_players_teams" FOREIGN KEY ("player_id") REFERENCES "players"("id"))
panic: ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "players" (SQLSTATE 42830)
```

If I remove `Tenant` from `BaseModel` it works.

Can I use `Composite Primary Key` this way?

**Can you suggest me why it's not working?**

**UPDATE**:

The problem it's generating this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "teams" (
    "id" bigserial,
    "created_at" timestamptz,
    "updated_at" timestamptz,
    "deleted_at" timestamptz,
    "tenant_id" BIGINT,
    "name" TEXT,
    "player_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( "id", "tenant_id" ),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_teams_tenant" FOREIGN KEY ( "tenant_id" ) REFERENCES "tenants" ( "id" ),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_players_teams" FOREIGN KEY ("player_id") REFERENCES "players"("id")
)
```

instead of:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "teams" (
    "id" bigserial,
    "created_at" timestamptz,
    "updated_at" timestamptz,
    "deleted_at" timestamptz,
    "tenant_id" BIGINT,
    "name" TEXT,
    "player_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( "id", "tenant_id" ),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_teams_tenant" FOREIGN KEY ( "tenant_id" ) REFERENCES "tenants" ( "id" ),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_players_teams" FOREIGN KEY ( "player_id", "tenant_id" ) REFERENCES "players" ( "id", "tenant_id" )
)
```

This is the difference:

```
- CONSTRAINT "fk_players_teams" FOREIGN KEY ("player_id") REFERENCES "players"("id")
+ CONSTRAINT "fk_players_teams" FOREIGN KEY ( "player_id", "tenant_id" ) REFERENCES "players" ( "id", "tenant_id" )
```

Is this my fault?

Answer (score 1):

Player needs an additional reference to the primary keys as the foreign key:

```
    type Player struct {
        BaseModel

        Name string
        Teams []Team `gorm:"foreignKey:player_id,tenant_id"`
    }
```